# Class S and class D transitor amplifier biasing

Tags: transistors, amplifier, power-amplifier

Where is Class D amplifier biased when it is off ?

Comment: I have never heard of a "class S" amplifier; you're going to have to elaborate on what that means.

Comment: @Hearth https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/amplifier/amplifier-classes.html

Answer (score 4):

All the amplifier classes from D to T (except G and H) are switch-based i.e. the output section does not work as a variable resistor.

So, the concept of biasing does not necessarily apply.

Comment: Class G and H are variable or multilevel linear types.

Comment: @TimWilliams I didn't know these classes even exist. I was lost after D, F, S, and T. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

Both D & S class amplifiers are typically implemented with MOSFETs as on-off switching elements.

So while the gates will have a default state (typically off) determined by a pull up or down resistor, I'd suggest the concept of bias (which is central to the linear operation of class A, B, AB & C amps implemented using BJT) isn't really relevant, because the linear range of the device is explicitly avoided.